# Should I create a new git repo every time I start a project redesign?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Occasionally I'll have a git repo setup for a website and a few years later I do a redesign of that site. The redesign is drastically different from the original website.

1. Should I start a new git repo? If so, should I rename the old one?
2. Should I work within the same repo and keep committing so anyone can
   see the websites adaptation over time. Even through totally new versions of 
   the site.

Thoughts/Concerns

- Starting a new git repo means that over time someone will have to
  look in multiple places to see the evolution of a project.
- Working within the same repo with a totally new design and new
  codebase (sometimes even moving from plain html site to a cms like
  Wordpress) doesn't show an accurate evolution of a specific set of
  code.
- I'd like to go for an approach that is clean. My typical path has
  been to start a new repo if the design is totally different. But
  curious if working in the same repo may be a better approach.

Curious about your opinions and approaches!

Comment: Why not branching? But if you ask for opinions, that's going to be off-topic. [Edit] your question to address the specific concerns you have.

Comment: @CodeCaster My concern with branching is I'm not working within the code that is already there. I'd pretty much branch and completely wipe out the code to create the new design. Then merge to master at some point. Good suggestion on the 'concerns'. Added that into my comment.

Answer (score 3):

> Yes, if it's a new project then create a new repo.

- If it's a continuation of the same project. You should use the same repo. Make use of tags and branches smartly. Follow the [semantics versioning](http://semver.org) scheme. Most projects are redisigned partially or completely over time.
- If you are starting from scratch. I mean really from scratch (e.g: new backend language, incompatible frameworks, new frontend framework) and you do not intend to reuse your old code then go for it and start a new project with its own repo.
- About your concerne of switching project to check the evolution. If it's totally different, you won't have to do that. If it's something you would do once a month or year. It would be useless to use the same repo just for that.

Hope it helps a bit

Answer (score -1):

Better to use the same Git repo, if you are using the same files and framework or model.

If it is a new design all together, then you can go with new repo.

Answer (score -1):

While fixing errors in a current version, just commit files.

When you complate current project and want to start new version of same project, create new branch.